# Почему продукт бродит?

Tags: этимология

Интересно было бы узнать, почему определенный процесс в некоторых продуктах называется "брожение"? Бродить - это ведь ходить без цели. А тут - просто химический процесс.
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Глагол бродить в значении "находиться в состоянии брожения" возник в результате переосмысления глагола бродить – "медленно передвигаться".
Бродят обычно туда и сюда. Когда вы бродите где-либо, вы медленно ходите в разных направлениях, не имея определённой цели. Когда жидкость бродит, переходит в кислое или винное брожение,она шевелится, вздымается, пучится, дробится от воздушных пузырей, которые как бы медленно ходят-бродят в разные стороны беспорядочно. Те же ассоциации, поэтому в одних словарях это одно из значений многозначного слова, в других - омоним. По смыслу равно  слову ферментировать

Answer (score 0):

Когда происходит процесс брожения, наблюдается явная активность массы, по суть химических процессов, их направленность внешне никак не обозначены. Отсюда следует сходство с глаголом бродить, имеющим значение "двигаться без определенной цели".

Таким образом, словом "бродить" мы обозначаем   не механические неопределенные перемещения, а  неявный, невидимый (до достижения цели) характер явления. И переносное значение выражения "брожение в умах" также связано с активизацией, которая еще плохо осознается и не имеет определенного направления.